# If constexpr ternary operator

Tags: c++

I have a simple snipped below:

```
template<typename>
struct function_traits;

template<typename Rv, typename... Args>
struct function_traits<Rv(Args...)>
{
    static constexpr const char _signature[] = {GetTypeChar<Rv>, '(', GetTypeChar<Args>()..., ')', '\0'};
}
```

where GetTypeChar returns character representing a type (i for integer, d for double et cetra).
This works really well for simple types, eg `function_traits<int(float,double)>::_signature` returns `i(f,d)` as expected.

Now Imagine I would have the ability to see whether it is an array or not by adding '[]' after the array, eg `double[]` would result in `d[]`.

I tried changing the signature to

```
static constexpr const char _signature[] = {GetTypeChar<Rv>(), '(', (std::is_array_v<Args> ? GetTypeChar<Args>(), '[', ']' : GetTypeChar<Args>())..., ')', '\0'};
```

but that seems to be completely ignored, and only things after `:` are evaluated.
Is something like this possible?

Comment: In function parameters, arrays are always passed by pointer or reference, never by value, eg: `int(float,double[])` is really `int(float,double*)`, so `std::is_array_v` will always return `false` in your example.  It would make more sense to use `std::is_pointer_v` to output `*` instead, and `std::is_reference_v` to output `&`. To detect an array, you would first have to detect a reference, remove the `&` via `std::remove_reference_t`, and then `std::is_array_v` might work on the resulting type.

Comment: @RemyLebeau oh damn, you're right! Changing `is_array_v` with `is_pointer_v` worked, Thank you. Now there is another problem that comma is not treated as an element separator but rather as a comma operator, thus only right side is considered. Any idea how to avoid it?

Comment: None that I know of. I really don't think you will be able to accomplish this in a single array intialization, like you are attempting to do. You really need a dynamic string instead

Comment: Do you have any idea how I would be able to add a * character after a pointer type while still maintaining the constexpr-ness? I don't need to have it in a single array initialization.

Comment: See [Compile-time string concatenation](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2017/06/28/compile-time-string-concatenation/)

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for the discussion, which led me to the solution (see answer below)

Answer (score 1):

Well, Initially I though I will be able to do this in a single array initialization, but the constexpr getter works well.
This is what I ended up with:

```
template<typename Tp>
constexpr void SetParamType(char*& dst)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_pointer_v<Tp>)
    {
        *dst++ = '[';
    }
    *dst++ = GetTypeChar<Tp>();
}

[[nodiscard]]
constexpr auto signature() const
{
    std::array<char, sizeof...(Args) * 2 + 4> out = {0};
    char * ptr = out.data();

    *ptr++ = GetTypeChar<return_type>();
    *ptr++ = '(';
    (SetParamType<Args>(ptr),...);
    *ptr++ = ')';
    *ptr++ = '\0';

    return out;
}
```

Please note that it would be wise to calculate the size of an array to exactly match the required length (which would not be hard after all, but for sake of simplicity I'll leave it as it is for now)